# Javascript Adobe Illustrator script -change strokewidth of all items

Tags: javascript, svg, scripting, adobe-illustrator

I have around 200 SVG files on which I need to change the strokecolor to gray and change the strokewidth of all lines to .2pt.

I would like to script out the equivalent of doing in the interface - 'Select ALL' and then entering the .2 pt for the strokewidth manually.

Right now, my script is changing all the colors to gray (working fine) and SOME of the lines to a stroke width of .2pt.

```
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for ( i = 0; i <doc.pathItems.length; i++ ) {
pathArt = doc.pathItems[i];
pathArt.strokeWidth = .2;
pathArt.strokeColor = makeColor(153,153,153);
pathArt.filled = false;
}

function makeColor(r,g,b){
var c = new RGBColor();
c.red   = r;
c.green = g;
c.blue  = b;
return c;
}
```

Perhaps I am not selecting all objects through the script correctly?
Is selecting the pathitems as I have done above the correct approach to achieve the equivalent of a CTRL-A, and then some operation manually?

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As of AI CS3, when a path is not stroked, the `.strokeColor` property applies while the `.strokeWidth` property doesn't.

Add the code `pathArt.Stroked = True;` to fix your problem

Also note that you don't iterate `CompoundPathItems`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete script, that will ask you to select the folder. So select folder that has 200 SVG files. This script will process all SVG files in the selected folder and change stroke color to gray and also change its width.

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
if (folder) {
    app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;
    var color = makeColor(153, 153, 153);
    var files = folder.getFiles("*.svg");
    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
        app.open(files[j]);
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
        for (i = 0; i < doc.pathItems.length; i++) {
            pathArt = doc.pathItems[i];
            pathArt.stroked = true;
            pathArt.strokeWidth = .2;
            pathArt.strokeColor = color;
            pathArt.filled = false;
        }
        doc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
        doc = null;
    }

}

function makeColor(r, g, b) {
    var c = new RGBColor();
    c.red = r;
    c.green = g;
    c.blue = b;
    return c;
}
```

You can change the script for locked and hidden items as well if you want to handle for locked and hidden items.